# Hibernate , Upon Transaction commit failure , find which entity failed

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

i have a simple loop which will insert some entities in the same transaction , into a DB2 database. The problem is that when committing the transaction and an insert fails due to duplicate ID , the exception i get from the driver is a plain message that indicates for which table the insert statement failed , but i need to find for which entity. Is there any way to translate the exception thrown from the Database??

the method is :

```
public final void saveAll(List<Entity> entities)
{
        StatelessSession session = getSaveQuerySession();
        Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();
        try 
        {
            for(Entity entity : entities)
                session.insert(entity);
            tr.commit();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            tr.rollback();
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
        }
}
```

the exception i got is :

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [com.MyEntity]
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2438)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2858)
```

EDIT

the inner exception is :

```
    java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: [SQL0803] Duplicate key value specified. 
Cause . . . . . : A unique index or unique constraint *N in *N exists over one or more columns of table MYENTITY in MYSCHEMA. 
The operation cannot be performed because one or more values would have produced a duplicate key in the unique index or constraint. Recovery  . . . :  
Change the statement so that duplicate keys are not produced.  
For information on what rows contain the duplicate key values, 
look at the previously listed messages in the job log (DSPJOBLOG command) or press F10 (Display messages in job log) on this display.
```

Comment: I think this is not the full stacktrace. Can you post the full stacktrace? Also try printing the entities before inserting them in db.

Comment: @RAS yes , the full stack trace contains the SQL Exception , which indicates  Duplicate key value specified. Cause . . . . . :   A unique index or unique constraint *N in *N exists ...... , which doesnt help at all. To print all the entities before transaction is even worse , imagine that i could have 1000 entities and the whole transaction fails just for one. i need to find that one.

Comment: @AntJavaDev Which version of Hibernate do you use?

Comment: @v.ladynev , Hibernate 3.5.0-Final , and i cannot update the version. Still i think it is not a hibernate's issue , but the DB2 Driver do not return a proper message , so i am looking for a workaround with hibernate in order to find the wrong entity.

Comment: @AntJavaDev, Stacktrace never lies. The actual reason is specified in that only which you're not sharing because you've assumed that it's not the actual reason. Printing objects in a for loop is only for debugging purpose. This is called debugging skill. Later on you have to remove it once your error get resolved.

Comment: @RAS , ok i have updated the stack trace , tell me what you can understand now . Do you want to provide you also the log with all the ids which as you said is a debugging skill and certainly helps in my case...............

Comment: @AntJavaDev I'm just showing you the way. Do it yourself first. Identify the entity for which you're getting exception. If you're not able to do so then you can surely post it here.

Comment: @RAS , now i get why you are confused , the insert will not happen during the `for loop` but after committing the transaction , so i dont know which entity failed , maybe you have to read the question carefully first

Comment: @AntJavaDev But in that case also, your entity will be assigned some id or value for the field for which unique index is created, that is mentioned in the stacktrace.

Comment: @RAS yes this is mentioned , but it doesn't indicate which ID is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101276/discussion-between-ras-and-antjavadev).